# AWS EC2 GPU with Vulkan API support

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gpu, vulkan

Does anyone know, if AWS provides GPUs which support the Vulkan API?

I've tried the g4ad, but without success.

Greetings,

Alexej

Comment: Almost certainly. They are the same GPUs. Make sure you have Vulkan drivers installed. On Linux they might be a different package, and perhaps Amazon Linux doesn't come with them by default.

Comment: Yes, I did not noticed, that the Radeon drivers are not installed by default. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

AMD Radeon drivers are not installed by default on Amazons AMIs (at least on Windows). I had to choose one from the AWS Marketplace:
Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Radeon-2022.06.15